# How can I decouple arguments which are requierd for different API implementations

Tags: java, api, design-patterns, architecture

There is a user API. I can send userId and get users. I need to create an interface and 2 implementations in my project. I will show the wrong implementation and wait for your suggestions on how to refactor this coupling.

```
public interface UserApi {
    User send(String userId, User user);
}
```

Original implementation uses only `userId` and sends it to real API

```
public class DefaultUserApi implements UserApi {
    @Override
    public User send(String userId, User user) {
        return getUserByIdFromAPI(userId);
    }

    private User getUserByIdFromAPI(String userId) {
        //calls API and get user
        return new User();
    }
}
```

The mock implementation uses only `user`. It changes some fields and returns this user.

```
public class MockUserApi implements UserApi {
    @Override
    public User send(String userId, User user) {
        return createUserBasedOnOriginalUser(user);
    }

    private User createUserBasedOnOriginalUser(User user) {
        User clonedUser = cloneUser(user);
        clonedUser.setName("name");
        return clonedUser;
    }

    private User cloneUser(User user) {
        return user;
    }
}
```

The main goal of `MockUserApi` is to get the user, change some fields and return it back.
So, that's why I should pass the user as an argument. It is a simple example, and not my code. I just saw it in our project and decided to try to refactor it.

**How can I avoid passing an extra `user` argument?**

The first thing that comes to mind is using UserRequest with 2 fields - `String userId` and  `User user` but maybe there is something better.

Comment: Why is there a `MockUserApi` in the production code?  That doesn't make sense.  Or is `MockUserApi` just there to support testing?

Comment: @ Andrew S `MockUserApi`  is used in a test server or dev computer. We don't want to call real API